# Parsing a text file for pattern and writing found pattern back to another file python 3.4

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to open a text file.  Parse the text file for specific regex patterns then when if I find that pattern I write the regex returned pattern to another text file.

Specifically a list of IP Addresses which I want to parse specific ones out of.

So the file may have

```
10.10.10.10
9.9.9.9
5.5.5.5
6.10.10.10
```

And say I want just the IPs that end in 10  (the regex I think I am good with)  My example looks for the 10.180.42, o4 41.XX IP hosts.  But I will adjust as needed.

I've tried several method and fail miserably at them all.  It's days like this I know why I just never mastered any language.  But I'm committed to Python so here goes.

```
import re

textfile = open("SymantecServers.txt", 'r')

matches = re.findall('^10.180\.4[3,1].\d\d',str(textfile))
print(matches)
```

This gives me empty backets.  I had to encase the textfile in the str function or it just puked.  I don't know if this is right.

This just failed all over the place no matter how I fine tuned it.

```
f = open("SymantecServers.txt","r")
o = open("JustIP.txt",'w', newline="\r\n")
for line in f:
    pattern = re.compile("^10.180\.4[3,1].\d\d")
    print(pattern)
    #o.write(pattern)
    #o.close()
   f.close()
```

I did get one working but it just returned the entire line (including netmask and other test like hostname which are all on the same line in the text file.  I just want IP)

Any help on how to read a text file and if it has a pattern of IP grab the full IP and write that into another text file so I end up with a text file with a list of just the IPs I want.  I am 3 hours into it and behind on work so going to do the first file by hand...

I am just at a loss what I am missing.  Sorry for being a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is it working:

```
>>> s = """10.10.10.10
... 9.9.9.9
... 5.5.5.5
... 10.180.43.99
... 6.10.10.10"""
>>> re.findall(r'10\.180\.4[31]\.\d\d', s)
['10.180.43.99']
```

- you do not really need to add line boundaries, as you're matching a very specific IP address, if your file does not have weird things like `'123.23.234.10.180.43.99.21354'` that you don't want to match, it should be ok!
- your syntax of `[3,1]` is matching either `3`, `1` or `,` and you don't want to match against a comma ;-)

about your function:

```
r = re.compile(r'10\.180\.4[31]\.\d\d')
with open("SymantecServers.txt","r") as f:
    with open("JustIP.txt",'w', newline="\r\n") as o:
        for line in f:
            matches = r.findall(line)
            for match in matches:
                o.write(match)
```

though if I were you, I'd extract IPs using:

```
r = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')
with open("SymantecServers.txt","r") as f:
    with open("JustIP.txt",'w', newline="\r\n") as o:
        for line in f:
            matches = r.findall(line)
            for match in matches:
                a, b, c, d = match.split('.')
                if int(a) < 255 and int(b) < 255 and int(c) in (43, 41) and int(d) < 100:
                    o.write(match)
```

or another way to do it:

```
r = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})')
with open("SymantecServers.txt","r") as f:
    with open("JustIP.txt",'w', newline="\r\n") as o:
        for line in f:
            m = r.match(line)
            if m:
                a, b, c, d = m.groups()
                if int(a) < 255 and int(b) < 255 and int(c) in (43, 41) and int(d) < 100:
                    o.write(match)
```

which uses the regex to split the IP address into groups.

Comment: It works.  I need to step through that when I am fresh.  But the file write is a single line.  No new line (windows machine but still...)  I'll import platform and os that may fix me.  I appreciate it.  You got the function exactly like I want.  The logic is eluding me a bit but I will work wiithit until I get it.  Thank you.

Comment: Wow.  Dude you added IP checking too... LOL

Comment: indeed, so you can check the IPs you want using ints, which is easier!

Comment: I had to change the write to o.wwite(match + \r\n) to get it to work with line breaks but it's perfect.  Now to 100% understand it.  Thank you sir.

Comment: Nice feature with the subnet check. The OP could create a list for each octet to modify in the future if he continues along the route of wanting to match only a particular subnet.

Comment: Why does this display right  print("no permit tcp " + match + '/32' + ' any eq 10082')  but I can't write with  a similar function.  If I have fixed (or even fluxuating) strings I want to concatenate to the write string how is it done. The write will not yuse the +?  It just writes the IP to the file in the previous help even with the + parts added to it

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that you're doing a `re.compile()` which creates a Regular Expression object in Python. You're forgetting to match.

You could try:

```
# This isn't the best way to match IP's, but if it fits for your use-case keep it for now.
pattern = re.compile("^10.180\.4[13].\d\d")

f = open("SymantecServers.txt",'r')
o = open("JustIP.txt",'w')

for line in f:
     m = pattern.match(line)

     if m is not None:
          print "Match: %s" %(m.group(0))
          o.write(m.group(0) + "\n")

f.close()
o.close()
```

Which is compiling the Python object, attempting to match the line against the compiled object, and then printing out that current match. I can avoid having to split my matches, but I have to pay attention to matching groups - therefore `group(0)`

You can also look at `re.search()` which you can do, but if you're running `search` enough times with the same regular expression, it becomes more worthwhile to use `compile`.

Also note that I moved the f.close() to the outside of the for loop.

Comment: your answer is wrong. You're keeping faulty handling of `open()` from the OP, and your solution is not working or solving OP's problems.

Comment: N.B.: use context managers, we're in 2014, and we're not doing python 2.2 anymore!

Comment: Well it's sort of working.  Better than what I had.  I am trying to fine tune it and will try yours as well.  I will indeed be searching thousands or IP patterns.  Maybe zillions and oh man I don't want to do it by hand....

Comment: His key error was only implementing `compile` instead of using `findall` or `match`. In my case I used `match` and writing the line to the output file if there was a match, but `open()` is not flawed. I wouldn't personally integrate the input and output `with` loops.

Comment: his key errors is that his pattern is wrong, that he is compiling the pattern at each iteration without actually matching using it. The open()/close() stuff is part of us teaching to newbies good programming practice!

Comment: Absolutely, I personally wouldn't match IP addresses in that fashion, as you had already mentioned to the OP - matching the set in brackets with commas would also match a comma. Mine is merely a quick and dirty solution where I didn't want to play with separating out the matches. Always appreciate feedback though lad.

Comment: and the open()/close() stuff is also important, because if there's an exception as you're writing output to the file, you won't close the file before leaving the application, and the last write may never be committed to the disk. In old python programming practice, a `try`/`finally` block was mandatory instead of the newer context manager, aka `with` statement.

Comment: True, it had slipped my mind that `with` already implements `try/finally` into that construct.